# Error publishing .net - core 3.1 Webservice with connectionString

Tags: c#, .net-core

When I try to publish the webService with the connectionString, I get the following error :

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\targets\TransformTargets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.TransformFiles.targets(192,5): Error MSB4018: The "TransformAppSettings" task failed unexpectedly.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.AppSettingsTransform.UpdateDestinationConnectionStringEntries(String destinationAppSettingsFilePath, ITaskItem[] destinationConnectionStrings)
   at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.TransformAppSettings.TransformAppSettingsInternal()
   at Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Tasks.TransformAppSettings.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

When I uncheck the `Use this connection string at runtime` option, I am able to publish it, but there is no data then on the `GET` method.

I tried to include the `connectionString` in the appsettings.Development.json as well, but with no luck.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you must save your connection string somewhere in your config files and use it when you initializing your context. also, you should add some parts of your code to help us figure what is wrong

Comment: Well, my connection string is saved in the appettings.json and there is no problem with my context initialization as my webservice is working properly with data if I debug it. I only have a problem when i am trying to publish it. If you still need some of my code, i will gladly give it to you.